# VBScript regex to support all accented characters

Tags: regex, validation, vbscript, non-ascii-characters

I have a below regex in VBScript,  Pattern:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$&\*])(?=.{8,20}$)
```

This validates "length bet 8-20, one small, Capital, special char and digit each"

Issue#1

When I entered `à` , it passes the validation, which shouldn't have happened. How to restrict it ?

Issue#2

Later, I realized I can use keyboard of any language so I modified my regex to support all accented letters, but its not working either.  Pattern:

```
^(?=.*\\p{L})(?!.*\s)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$&\*])(?=.{8,20}$)
```

Does VBScript allow to use `p{L}` regex ? any alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

Your current pattern actually [does not validate à](https://regex101.com/r/fSovmt/1).  But it is slightly off and won't implement what you have in mind.  Try this instead:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$&*])[A-Za-z0-9!@#$&*]{8,20}$
                                                  ^^^ important
```

This says to assert that there is at least one:

- lowercase letter
- uppercase letter
- digit
- special character (!@#$&*)

Then, it matches any of the above four types of characters 8 to 20 times.

The critical problem with your pattern, and the reason it would admit accented characters, provided the other assertions pass, is because of this:

```
(?=.{8,20})
```

Your final lookahead *does* enforce 8 to 20 characters, but it admits *any* character.  Instead, I use a range limited only to the possible types of characters you want to appear.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked. How should I modify my regex to support all the characters since p{L} is not working for me in VBScript

Comment: @vishalshah What are "all the characters?"  Can you be more specific about what you are really trying to do here?

Comment: all the characters means a-z, A-Z, accented characters like àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóú. I tried  
    Pattern = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$&\*])(?=[A-Za-z0-9!@#$&*\u00C0-\u024F]{8,20}$)"    which is working fine but not sure Is this right way to do it? or may be I am missing something. Help me out

Comment: @vishalshah If `\u00C0-\u024F` matches the accented characters which you want to allow, then the pattern looks fine to me.

Comment: In html `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]"` can be changed to `pattern="[\p{L}0-9-_. ]"` to extended the support of all the accented characters. Wanted such clean solution but I guess VBScript has its own way of working....!!!!

Comment: Well one could argue that a Unicode range might be preferred, because it gives you finer grain control.  E.g. you might want to support only certain accented characters.

Comment: Funny thing is
    `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$&*])[A-Za-z0-9!@#$&*]{8,20}$`  ,this pattern matches (abc"123). Double Quote is bypassing the regex I guess.

Comment: @vishalshah That pattern doesn't seem to match what you claim ([see here](https://regex101.com/r/pPLOUR/1)).  Maybe there is something going on with your code.

Comment: true that and I will have a look at my logs for the same, but I am not sure same Regex will work in VBScript. For example [See here](https://regex101.com/r/KxViZv/1), this regex support accented characters but same will not work in VBScript.